# Undoing javascript replace function

Tags: javascript, html, regex

The goal of this function is to toggle a text input from allowing between numbers(and /) only and allowing default characters depending on if the "Query" option is selected in a select tag.

I'm doing something like this:

```
function ifQueryDisableDefVal(selectId, textInput){
  if(document.getElementById(selectId).value == 'Query'){
    var numInput;
    numInput = document.getElementById(textInput);
    numInput.onkeydown = numInput.onblur = numInput.onkeyup = function(){
      numInput.value = numInput.value.replace(/[^0-9\/]+/,"");
    }
  }else{
  //What I need help with.
  }
}
```

The if statement works just fine, except I'm having troubles "reverting", so to speak, the text input to allow default characters again (the else).

-Thanks in advance

Comment: How about moving the if/else statement into the keyup handler?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`numInput.onkeydown = null` will remove the event handler. Do this for all events you've handled.

Answer (score 0):

As @Bergi said you could try this:

```
var numInput = document.getElementById(textInput);
numInput.onkeydown = numInput.onblur = numInput.onkeyup = function(){
  if(document.getElementById(selectId).value==='Query')
  {
      numInput.value = numInput.value.replace(/[^0-9\/]+/,"");
  }
}
```

Hope this is helpful for you.